# php unit-testing, eclipse PDT, makegood, xdebug

Tags: eclipse, phpunit, makegood

Is there any way to force makegood stop on breakpoints in order to inspect vars,etc ?
I installed eclipse indigo 3.7 + PDT tools, secondly I configured xdebug and it works during plain debug. at last I installed makegood from marketplace and enabled it's feature "Debug Test" and yet it doesn't stop at breakpoints instead it shows me report, which is correct, plus some buggy lines like:

```
/mnt/public/midnight/www/sandbox/makegood/Tests/makeGoodTest.php:11
/home/midnight/Software/eclipse/plugins/com.piece_framework.makegood.stagehand_testrunner_1.9.0.v201201241509/resources/php/PEAR/Stagehand/TestRunner/Runner/PHPUnitRunner.php:112
/home/midnight/Software/eclipse/plugins/com.piece_framework.makegood.stagehand_testrunner_1.9.0.v201201241509/resources/php/PEAR/Stagehand/TestRunner/TestRunner.php:79
/home/midnight/Software/eclipse/plugins/com.piece_framework.makegood.stagehand_testrunner_1.9.0.v201201241509/resources/php/PEAR/Stagehand/TestRunner/TestRunnerCLIController.php:325
/home/midnight/Software/eclipse/plugins/com.piece_framework.makegood.stagehand_testrunner_1.9.0.v201201241509/resources/php/PEAR/Stagehand/TestRunner/TestRunnerCLIController.php:175
/home/midnight/Software/eclipse/plugins/com.piece_framework.makegood.stagehand_testrunner_1.9.0.v201201241509/resources/php/PEAR/Stagehand/CLIController.php:101
/home/midnight/Software/eclipse/plugins/com.piece_framework.makegood.stagehand_testrunner_1.9.0.v201201241509/resources/php/bin/phpunitrunner.php:80
```

My `/etc/php5/conf.d/xdebug.ini`:

```
zend_extension="/usr/lib/php5/20090626/xdebug.so"
xdebug.profiler_enable = Off
xdebug.default_enable = On
xdebug.remote_enable = On
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry but I don't use makegood but I do know that xdebug has a function you can call from the code to trigger a break.

```
xdebug_break();
```

> bool xdebug_break()
>
> Emits a breakpoint to the debug client. This
>   function makes the debugger break on the specific line as if a normal
>   file/line breakpoint was set on this line.

I hope this will be of some help.

Answer (score 0):

There is a button "Debug Test" for this in the MakeGood View.
To use if configure Eclipse Debuging using e.g. XDebug and then set a breakpoint and run your tests.

See https://wiki.eclipse.org/Debugging_using_XDebug